# Issues obtaining ssl certificate

Tags: ssl, docker-compose, lets-encrypt, traefik

**BACKGROUND**

I am trying to setup the traefik dashboard to be accessible at **sub.domain.com**, and secure it automatically via a Let's Encrypt SSL certificate. Using the configuration files below, I am successful in setting up the container and making the dashboard accessible via https://sub.domain.com.

I have multiple A records pointing to the same IP, which is a VPS:

- sub.domain.com
- server1.domain.com

**PROBLEM**

Upon loading the dashboard page I get an untrusted certificate error.

**LOGS & CONFIGS**

- Examining the Traefik dashboard certificate shows it's a Traefik self-signed cert.
- Looking at the container logs, I can see the following

  ```
  time="2018-01-23T04:47:53Z" level=info msg="Generating ACME Account..."
  time="2018-01-23T04:48:11Z" level=debug msg="Building ACME client..."
  time="2018-01-23T04:48:11Z" level=info msg=Register...
  time="2018-01-23T04:48:12Z" level=debug msg=AgreeToTOS...
  time="2018-01-23T04:48:12Z" level=info msg="Preparing server traefik &{Network: Address::8080 TLS:<nil> Redirect:<nil> Auth:<nil> WhitelistSourceRange:[] Compress:false ProxyProtocol:<nil> ForwardedHeaders:0xc4202a2940} with readTimeout=0s writeTimeout=0s idleTimeout=3m0s"
  time="2018-01-23T04:48:12Z" level=info msg="Retrieving ACME certificates..."
  time="2018-01-23T04:48:12Z" level=info msg="Retrieved ACME certificates"
  time="2018-01-23T04:48:12Z" level=info msg="Starting provider *docker.Provider {"Watch":true,"Filename":"","Constraints":null,"Trace":false,"DebugLogGeneratedTemplate":false,"Endpoint":"unix:///var/run/docker.sock","Domain":"bendwyer.net","TLS":null,"ExposedByDefault":false,"UseBindPortIP":false,"SwarmMode":false}"
  time="2018-01-23T04:48:12Z" level=info msg="Starting server on :443"
  time="2018-01-23T04:48:12Z" level=info msg="Starting server on :8080"
  time="2018-01-23T04:48:12Z" level=info msg="Testing certificate renew..."
  ```
- Checking `acme.json` I can see that the file has been populated with Let's Encrypt information, but the certificate sections are blank.

`traefik.toml`

```
defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]
debug = true

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
    [entryPoints.http.redirect]
    entryPoint = "https"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

[acme]
email = "name@domain.com"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
[acme.httpChallenge]
  entryPoint = "http"
OnHostRule = true

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "domain.com"
watch = true
exposedbydefault = false
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:1.5-alpine
    command: --web
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    restart: always
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.backend=sub"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:sub.domain.com"
      - "traefik.port=8080"
      - "traefik.frontend.auth.basic=user:htpasswd"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
      - "./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml"
      - "./acme.json:/acme.json"
    container_name: traefik
    networks:
      - default
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must change your configuration like that:

```
[acme]
email = "name@domain.com"
storage = "acme.json"
entryPoint = "https"
OnHostRule = true # <-----------  
[acme.httpChallenge]
  entryPoint = "http"
```